# Linux and x32-ABI - How to use?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, 64bit, 32bit

**Intro**
I just moved to a 64bit installation and I'm experiencing big difference in memory usage ( especially for app like chrome, firefox, mysql and java apps ):

- While before 4gb were enough now they are soon exhausted !

This is a is well known side effect of 64bit OSs anyway 64bit brings also some other advantage.

Beside ram is very cheap, there are some netbook that still ship with 1/2gb ram ...
... and here it comes `x32 ABI`: a kernel feature that is meant exactly to limit this issue.

**What is x32 ABI:**
according to [this pdf](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1528222/files/LHCb-TALK-2013-060.pdf) it provide great memory advantage compared to a 64bit normal OS (even 40% enhancement).

Now if I have understood **x32-ABI requires**:

- Linux Kernel 3.4 compiled with CONFIG_X86_X32=y
- Gcc 4.7
- Binutils 2.22
- Glibc 2.16
- Recompiling all system libraries, required by an application, with gcc -mx32

I know Debian and other distros they are actually shipping libs with 32x-ABI support but I cannot find any documentation to set up this functionality ( I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit )

I would like to use this question to help me and others to collect information because I think this is a very interesting feature.

In particular my goal would be run one app ( such as chrome or firefox or mysql ) using x32-ABI.

Comment: How do you take those libs with x32 ABI support to use in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

**Debian**
I haven't tried yet but here some instruction to run X32-ABI on debian:
https://wiki.debian.org/X32Port

**Arch**
Here a repository with many X32 packages (such as chromium, mysql):
https://github.com/fantix/ArchLinux-x32

Comment: So you need to boot kernel with "syscall.x32=y" option.

Comment: Please take notice that parameter would only work on Debian (and derivatives maybe?) that include [this patch](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/blob/master/debian/patches/features/x86/x86-make-x32-syscall-support-conditional.patch) since 4 years or so. For whatever reason it was never accepted into vanilla mainline, which still has everything gated exclusively via `CONFIG_X86_X32`

Answer (score 0):

For the adventurous, you can recompile your own kernel, and glibc etc: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/x32

Note also that it's "a lot" easier to find distro support for running 32-bit binaries on 64-bit kernels, so you could just compile for that (`-m32`) instead of for x32-bit (`-mx32`), losing some benefit, but easier to setup, still get some RAM savings.